# How to use multiple methods in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import sys
import time

import NO_1
import NO_2
import NO_3
import NO_4
import NO_5

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.time()

    NO_1.NO_1()
    NO_2.NO_2()
    NO_3.NO_3()
    NO_4.NO_4()
    NO_5.NO_5()

    end = time.time() - start
```

This is my Python Code.
NO_1,2,3,4,5 are all different methods, but I want to run them simultaneously and reduce execution time.
There are no argument values.

I tried to do it with multi-processing, but most of the blogs suggested only run one method multiple times, and I couldn't find a way to run different methods simultaneously.

Is there a way to run different methods simultaneously?

Comment: Of course there is.  You just need to create 5 `Process` objects, one with each target.  Or, create a single function that accepts an integer and dispatch to your others from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing

import NO_1
import NO_2
import NO_3
import NO_4
import NO_5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    processes = [
        multiprocessing.Process(target=NO_1.NO_1),
        multiprocessing.Process(target=NO_2.NO_2),
        multiprocessing.Process(target=NO_3.NO_3),
        multiprocessing.Process(target=NO_4.NO_4),
        multiprocessing.Process(target=NO_5.NO_5)
    ]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    end = time.time() - start
```

Take a look in [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) documentation for more info

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using the `map` examples you found and a dispatch routine:

```
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

import NO_1
import NO_2
import NO_3
import NO_4
import NO_5

funcs = [
    NO_1.NO_1,
    NO_2.NO_2,
    NO_3.NO_3,
    NO_4.NO_4,
    NO_5.NO_5
]

def dispatch(n):
    funcs[n]()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.time()
    with Pool(5) as p:
        p.map( dispatch, [0,1,2,3,4] )
    end = time.time() - start
```